# ADF Pipelines and Triggers

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Lets assume a scenario where pipeline A runs every day and pipeline B runs once in every month and it is dependent on pipeline A (pipeline B should trigger after successful completion of pipeline A).

Using scheduled trigger, we cannot have hard dependencies between 2 pipelines, where as with tumbling window, we cannot exactly specify the day which the pipeline B should run(it has only two options, minutes and hours where as scheduled trigger has months and weeks also)

Both the triggers has its disadvantages with respect to this scenario.

What could be the best possible solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You can Run Pipeline A everyday, and have an IF check that checks if its a specific date today, then run Pipeline B if TRUE and nothing if FALSE.

[image]

For the settings of If Condition, you can use this as variable, if you want to run it every 1st of every month:

```
@Contains('01',Substring(formatDateTime(utcnow()),8,2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it is good solution, but can we drive the solution using triggers instead of chain of pipelines?

Comment: If you want two different triggers, the pipelines can't know anything about run status of other pipelines. Then you would need a SQL table or something that have historic values of status of other pipelines. If you want this pipeline to wait for other pipeline to complete, you would need some kind of "Until" logic. I think this solution will serve your purpose best.